# Visualforce: Selected InputCheckbox value not updating

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller-extension, inputcheckboxes

> ** **UPDATED (Simplified my custom object to no longer be a wrapper within a wrapper)** **

Since posting I've made some adjustments, so at the moment I have a custom wrapper object called `ShipmentInvoiceLineItem` which basically represents 1 of 2 possible custom objects as well as a `boolean` *selected* value:

```
public class ShipmentInvoiceLineItem {

    public Custom1__c c1 {get; set;}
    public Custom2 c2 {get; set;}
    public String accountId {get; set;}
    public String shipmentId {get; set;}
    public Boolean selected {get; set;}

    public ShipmentInvoiceLineItem(Custom1 c1, Boolean selected){
        this.c1 = c1;
        this.accountId = c1.Shipment__r.Account__c;
        this.shipmentId = c1.Shipment__c;
        this.selected = selected;
    }

    public ShipmentInvoiceLineItem(Custom2 c2, Boolean selected){
        this.c2 = c2;
        this.accountId = c2.Account__c;
        this.shipmentId = c2.Shipment__c;
        this.selected = selected;
    }

}
```

On the front end I have multiple `<apex:repeat>` fields that iterates through custom maps I created in my controller (this way I could group by Accounts and Shipment types without my previous complex multi-dimensional map object). The issue I'm having is with the actual form within each of these groupings. Within the form I iterate through my wrapper object like so:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!ShipmentInvoiceLineItemsByShipment[shipment.Id]}" var="item">
```

***Note:*** ShipmentInvoiceLineItemsByShipment is structured as list of `ShipmentInvoiceLineItems` indexed by their shipment Id `Map<String,List<ShipmentInvoiceLineItem>>`

Visually everything appears to be working fine, as expected the boxes are pre-checked (assuming the user will want these to be checked), but when I uncheck any of of the checkboxes and submit it like so:

[image]

When I attempt to iterate through the `ShipmentInvoiceLineItemsByShipment` it doesn't appear to have SET the boolean value to false as expected.

```
public PageReference markLineItemsAsPaid() {
    // I passed this as a parameter in <apex:commandLink>
    String id = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('processID'); 
    for(ShipmentInvoiceLineItem lineItem : getShipmentInvoiceLineItemsByShipment().get( id )){
        if(lineItem.selected == TRUE) {
            System.debug('::SELECTED::');
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Any ideas of what could be the problem here?

Comment: Well, you initiate `selected` as TRUE so the real issue is why are they not checked when displayed? Relevant VF page code will be needed. What is your button code?

Comment: They are checked when displayed, but then I unchecked one so that I can verify I'm only about to `UPDATE` the selected items

Comment: do you have action="immediate" on the `Mark as Paid` button? that would prevent any of the unchecked line items from invoking the setter for `selected`.  same issue if you are using actionRegions that aren't encompassing enough.  The debug log will show each setter getting called with its value

Comment: No I don't have that set on any (I read about that as well). Although I just realized that the last iteration of the Shipment Order forms works which leads me to believe that the problem is because of a shared ID, so I tried to add an iteration number to the form like so: `<apex:form id="soAccountingForm-{!shipment.Id}">` but got the following error: `Error: Literal value is required for attribute id in <apex:form>`

Comment: The more test I run it appears evident that the issue is with a duplicate form ID, and at the moment I can't find a way to create a dynamic ID for each form based on the `<apex:repeat>` iteration. Any ideas on that? Pretty sure that would resolve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind [the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_form.htm) on `<apex:form>` states:

> *"As of API version 18.0, ​**this tag can't be a child component of** `<apex:repeat>`"*

So, your `<apex:form>` should be outside of your `<apex:repeat>`

Then, you should `apex:actionRegion` tags so that you only have one form tag.  With this you can submit the data by region instead of multiple forms as stated here:

http://th3silverlining.com/2009/10/19/multiple-forms-in-a-single-visualforce-page/